# RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tags: python, edit-mode, operator, object-mode, timer

I want my object to switch between *Edit mode* and *Object mode* every one second, So I wrote this code:

```
import bpy

def tester():
    obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
    if (bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT'):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)  
    else:  
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    return 1

bpy.app.timers.register(tester)
```

but I got this error message :

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following script for Blender 3.2 and above. You can read more about context here [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

```
import bpy

area_type = 'VIEW_3D' # change this to use the correct Area Type context you want to process in
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

if len(areas) <= 0:
    raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

def mode_set(mode, toggle):
    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        window=bpy.context.window,
        area=areas[0],
        regions=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
        screen=bpy.context.window.screen
    ):

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=mode, toggle=toggle)


def tester():
    obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
    if (bpy.context.mode == 'OBJECT'):
        mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
    else:  
        mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)
    return 1

bpy.app.timers.register(tester)
```